# Is there a full code to change the LOCALE in SASonDemand?

Tags: sas, locale

I am using SAS on Demand for Academics, which is online (if it makes any difference). I am running the following code:

```
/*import dataset*/
proc import datafile="/home/********/cars.csv" 
out=work.cars
dbms=csv
replace;
run;
```

and i get the error:

> ERROR 14-12: Invalid option value EN_CY for SAS option LOCALE.

Please anyone that can help how to solve this? I have already changed the default language to English on Google.

Comment: I suspects that PROC IMPORT only cares about LOCALE setting to help it figure out how to interpret ambiguous date strings.  See is setting the DATESTYLE option will make PROC IMPORT not care what your LOCALE setting is.  `options datestyle=mdy;` Otherwise just change the LOCALE setting itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the locale with an `options` statement, so that should be easy enough.

```
options locale=English_UnitedStates;
```

Or whatever the right locale is.  See [this table](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/nlsref/p0kcqbj7zsjq23n1lfyrcgtwiy5q.htm) for the list of all possible locales; make sure it matches the `OPTIONS ENCODING` value.